# Symfony2. Создать checkbox'ы на основе коллекции сущностей

Tags: form, symfony2

Есть коллекция объектов (выборка из базы). Цель - сделать на основе этой коллекции форму, которая будет отрисовывать чекбоксы для каждой сущности, и передавать значение поля id этой сущности. Как делал я:

```
$builder
    ->add('order', 'entity', [
        'required'      => false,
        'class'         => 'AppBundle:Order',
        'property'      => 'id',
        'multiple'      => true,
        'expanded'      => true,
     ])
```

Проблема в том, что при таком подходе получается огромное количество запросов к базе данных, и это при том что мне вообще дополнительную выборку делать не нужно так как коллекция выборки уже имеется на руках, нужно только создать форму на её основе, чтобы чекбоксы передавали значение полей id каждого объекта коллекции. Отсюда делаю вывод что type entity не подходит, ибо он провоцирует отдельный запрос для каждой сущности. Как сделать по другому я ума не приложу.

Учавствуюте 3 файла, LocalStatusType.php - класс формы, содержимое:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

use AppBundle\Entity\Order;

class LocalStatusType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('status', 'choice', [
                'choices' => Order::LOCAL_STATUSES,
                'constraints' => [
                    new Assert\Choice([
                        'choices' => Order::LOCAL_STATUSES
                    ])
                ]
            ])
            ->add('order', 'entity', [
                'required'      => 'false',
                'class'         => 'AppBundle:Order',
                'property'      => 'id',
                'property_path' => '[id]',
                'multiple'      => true,
                'expanded'      => true,
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver
            ->setDefaults([
                'data_class'        => null,
                'csrf_protection'   => false
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'local_status_form';
    }
}
```

Класс сущности Order.php, большой из за геттеров и сеттеров, да и свойств не мало. Скажу только что так есть 1 поле связанное one-to-one с сущностью sub_order.php, но я думаю это не имеет значения в контексте вопроса, sub_order меня не интересует.

Ну и контроллер, в нём через Query Builder формируется запрос, так же там используется knp_paginator, на выходе получается объект пагинатора, из которого я с помощью getItems() извлекаю коллекцию объектов в переменную $orders_collection, а далее:

```
$local_status_form = $this
    ->createForm(new LocalStatusType, $orders_collection)
    ->createView()
;

return compact('orders', 'local_status_form'); // orders это объект пагинатора, этот экшен отвечает за отрисовку.
```

Есть ещё один, отвечает за изменение статуса, обрабатывает форму:

```
/**
 * Handler of status form.
 * @Method("POST")
 * @Route("/")
 */
public function changeStatusAction(Request $request)
{
    $local_status_form = $this
        ->createForm(new LocalStatusType)
        ->handleRequest($request)
    ;

    $data = $local_status_form->getData();
    $em = $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');

    foreach($data['id'] as $order) {
        $order->setLocalStatus($data['status']);
        $em->persist($order);
    }

    $em->flush();

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('app_order_index'));
}
```

В общем всё.

Суть такая, у сущности Order есть поле local_status, форма должна менять значение этого поля у всех выбранных чекбоксами сущностей. Т.е. я отмечаю нужные мне записи (ставлю галочки в чекбоксах), в выпадающем списке выбираю новый статус и отправляю форму. Сейчас всё работает, но криво, по описанным мной ранее причинам.

Ах да, ещё в шаблоне:

```
// ...
{{ form_start(local_status_form) }}
    {{ form_widget(local_status_form.status, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
<input type ="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" value="change statuses">
// начинается цикл
    {% for order in orders %}
        {{ form_widget(local_status_form.order[order.id])}} // отрисовываются чекбоксы
    // отрисовываются остальные поля
    {% endfor %}
{{ form_end(local_status_form, {'render_rest': false }) }}
```

Comment: danil, в createForm() вторым аргументом я передаю $orders_collection, но в методе класса где я создаю форму использовать её уже не получается: "Notice: Undefined variable: orders_collection", и ещё, метод getUsers() из примера это обычный геттер из класса сущности? Насчёт второго сомневаюсь, т.к. он вернёт только конкретный id конкретной сущности, а не коллекцию как написано в примере.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться query_builder или choices

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#using-a-custom-query-for-the-entities

Добавлено:

> danil, в createForm() вторым аргументом я передаю $orders_collection, но в методе класса где я создаю форму использовать её уже не получается: "Notice: Undefined variable: orders_collection", и ещё, метод getUsers() из примера это обычный геттер из класса сущности? Насчёт второго сомневаюсь, т.к. он вернёт только конкретный id конкретной сущности, а не коллекцию как написано в примере.

getUsers() - да, это обычный геттер, который вернет коллекцию, поэтому он и используется в choices.

У меня нет возможности писать комментарии, т.к. недостаточно еще баллов репутации. Уточните тогда свой вопрос. Какие классы (файлы) используете и где вызываете, можно даже их содержимое. Потому что из вопроса не очень ясно.
Форма у Вас содержит заказ, а она связана с какой либо сущностью?

createForm вторым аргументом принимает сущность (модель) для инициализации формы. 
http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/forms.html#building-forms
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.8/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php#L280

Добавлено №2

Я бы сделал так. Создал класс для формы заказа с полями которые необходимо менять. Здесь стоит отметить, что есть два варианта, которыми можно будет пользоваться в этом случае:

- добавить в форму заказа флажок "need_update", и затем в контроллере проверять что этот флажок отмечен и соответственно менять таким заказам статус
- а можно добавить поле "status" и менять статусы сразу в форме и при сохранении ничего кроме flush делать не надо. Второй вариант будет выглядеть примерно так:
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для примера можно посмотреть вот...
Контроллер:

```
class OrderController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="order_index")
     * @Method("GET")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        $pagination = $this->getPagination($request);
        $form = $this->getFormBuilder($pagination)->getForm();

        return array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'pagination' => $pagination,
        );
    }

    /**
     *
     * @Route("/", name="orders_update")
     * @Method("PUT")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function updateOrdersAction(Request $request)
    {
        $pagination = $this->getPagination($request);
        $form = $this->getFormBuilder($pagination)->getForm();
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        /** @var $em EntityManager */
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            foreach ($form->get('orders') as $order) {
                // Здесь ваша логика
                // Например если отмечен чек бокс "need_update" то изменить статус заказа
            }
            $em->flush();

            $pagination = $this->getPagination($request);
            $form = $this->getFormBuilder($pagination)->getForm();
        }

        return array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'pagination' => $pagination,
        );
    }

    /**
     * @param \Knp\Component\Pager\Pagination\PaginationInterface $pagination
     * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder
     */
    private function getFormBuilder(\Knp\Component\Pager\Pagination\PaginationInterface $pagination)
    {
        $defaultData = array('orders' => $pagination);
        $builder = $this->createFormBuilder($defaultData);
        $builder
            ->setAction($this->generateUrl('orders_update'))
            ->setMethod('PUT')
            ->add('orders', 'collection', array(
                'type' => new FormType\OrderIndexType()
            ))
            ->add('save', 'submit', array(
                'label' => 'Сохранить'
            ))
        ;

        return $builder;
    }

    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @return \Knp\Component\Pager\Pagination\PaginationInterface
     */
    private function getPagination(Request $request)
    {
        /** @var $em EntityManager */
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $rep = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Order');

        $query = $rep->createQueryBuilder('o')
            ->orderBy('o.priority', 'ASC')
            ->addOrderBy('o.id', 'ASC')
            ->getQuery()
        ;
        $page = $request->query->get('page', 1);

        $paginator = $this->get('knp_paginator');
        $pagination = $paginator->paginate(
            $query,
            $page,
            5
        );

        return $pagination;
    }
}
```

И форма:

```
class OrderIndexType extends AbstractType
{
        /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('need_update', 'checkbox')
            ->add('status', 'choice', array(
                'choices' => array(
                    1 => 'Скрыть',
                    0 => 'Показать',
                )
            ))
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Entity\Order'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'order';
    }
}
```